# If a dream tells us about future events, how likely is it for those events to happen?

Tags: dream, future

I've read a lot of dream interpretations on http://www.myislamicdream.com/. A lot of them tell the dreamer about the events of the future. If a person sees something in a dream and its **interpretation tells him something about the future, how likely is it for those events to happen?** **Is the dreamer bound my fate to suffer from what the dream told him/her? Or can the dreamer avoid those events from happening?**

For example, the website explains that "Falling in a blood well means the dreamer will be unfortunately involved in a crime or plagued with illicit money". Now, it is only sensible for the dreamer to try to avoid this outcome at all costs.

Comment: I don't see any relevance to the topic of the site. Also read in [our Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3411/13438).

Comment: Brother, I'm talking in the context of islam. The website myislamicdream is a database of islamic dream interpretations, mostly by Ibn Sirin. And I'm asking a question based on those interpretations. Maybe I've not done a good enough job at explaining myself but I hope you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: dream interpretation is off-topic as it is not part of the teaching of Islam in the sense that can be covered here.

Comment: Brother, I'm not very educated in this subject. Is dream interpretation prohibited in Islam?

Comment: you may find posts explaining the Islamic view.

Comment: Okay so I read this article: https://www.farhathashmi.com/articles-section/belief-and-introspection/the-reality-of-dreams/ and Prophet PBUH said, "Do not tell anyone how the Shaytaan is messing about with you in your dreams" and "If any one of you sees a dream that he dislikes, let him spit to his left three times, and seek refuge with Allaah from the Shaytaan three times, and turn over from the side on which he was sleeping". So it seems that I was forgetting that harm can only come by Allah and distressing dreams only come from Shaytaan. Is this the answer brother @Medi1Saif?

Comment: I don't think there exists any methodology of dream interpretation that is adopted from Qur'an or Sunnah. That alone makes them hardly credible, if at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreams come in three forms:

1)Jumbled dreams i.e. just based on what you have experience in the past i.e. what the Kings advisors in surah Jusuf suggested the king had 12:44

2) from shaytan

3) from Allah.

The problem with dream interpretation is that if you associate objects with meanings this can become a form of superstition. Living a life of superstition is not nice. You might have a dream that has a bad meaning and thus you feel bad all day as if something bad is going to happen, but in reality you have nothing to feel bad about. And in the reverse situation you might have a dream with good meaning and thus feel good all day as if something good is going to happen, but in reality you have nothing to feel good about. Thus you live a life that is full of darkness and light, but  the light is actually a false light. My advice to you is not to get into this. The other problem with dreams it can lead to shirk, as shaytan might tell you through dreams to do this or that for worldly benefits, thus you become someone that relies on Shaytan, as Muslims we must only rely on Allah.